# wxpython: How to add am image in text control

Tags: python, wxpython

Am trying to display image in text control but it display only binary characters.

But is their any way I can archive this or its impossible dream to do it in wxpython

Please help I will need this agently.
   Thank you advance

Here are the source codes that I have so far

```
import wx
    class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
        def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
            super(MainFrame,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)

            self.main_panel = MainPanel(self,-1)

    class MainPanel(wx.Panel):
        def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
            super(MainPanel,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)

            img1 = wx.Image("coins.png", wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY)
            w = img1.GetWidth()
            h = img1.GetHeight()
            img1 = img1.Scale(w/2, h/2)

            sb1 = wx.StaticBitmap(self, -1, wx.BitmapFromImage(img1))

            self.txtctrl = wx.TextCtrl(self,-1,"display image here",size=(500,300),pos=(20,10))



class App(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        mainframe = MainFrame(None,-1,title="Display image in txt ctrl",size=(600,400))
        mainframe.Show()
        mainframe.Center()
        return True

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App();
    app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot put an image directly inside a regular `wx.TextCtrl` widget. That is currently impossible as they just don't support that. However, you can put an image into a `RichTextCtrl` widget. If you haven't downloaded it yet, be sure to get the wxPython demo from the project's [website](http://www.wxpython.org) as it has a good example. Here are a couple links:

- http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/richtext.RichTextCtrl.html
- http://play.pixelblaster.ro/blog/archive/2008/10/08/richtext-control-with-wxpython-saving-and-loading

If you just want to put an image in your application, then `wx.Image` is your friend (as John already mentioned).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with wx.Image read [this](http://wiki.wxpython.org/WorkingWithImages)

you can also see a more complex example [here](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/03/26/creating-a-simple-photo-viewer-with-wxpython/)